# how to escape a variable in Lua

Tags: escaping, lua, pattern-matching

is there a way to escape an entire variable in Lua? like:

```
local blah = some_pattern
string.gsub(blah, "-", "%-")
```

The variable "blah" changes, and is used elsewhere in another pattern match. Whenever "blah" has a magic character in it, the second pattern match, that is done elsewhere, fails.

So I need to handle escaping the various magic characters at least, in "blah".

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bit unclear what you're asking for here: a way to call your escaping function whenever a variable's value is set, or how to escape a string for pattern matching.

A variable is just storage for a value. You can't cause a general operation to happen when a local variable is set. So if you change the value of `blah`, it is up to you to escape the string properly again.

If you're asking how to escape a string for pattern matching, it would be something like this:

```
blah = blah:gsub(blah, "([...])", "%%%1")
```

Where `...` is the list of characters that you need to escape. The Lua reference manual has a list you can use. Note that, since this is a pattern, these characters *must* be escaped here.

Answer (score 12):

The easiest way is to escape all punctuation characters and not to worry about magic characters:

```
newpattern = string.gsub(pattern, "%p", "%%%1")
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [this function](https://github.com/lua-nucleo/lua-nucleo/blob/master/lua-nucleo/string.lua#L137-158):

```
local escape_lua_pattern
do
  local matches =
  {
    ["^"] = "%^";
    ["$"] = "%$";
    ["("] = "%(";
    [")"] = "%)";
    ["%"] = "%%";
    ["."] = "%.";
    ["["] = "%[";
    ["]"] = "%]";
    ["*"] = "%*";
    ["+"] = "%+";
    ["-"] = "%-";
    ["?"] = "%?";
  }

  escape_lua_pattern = function(s)
    return (s:gsub(".", matches))
  end
end
```